# Protractor cannot find element after re-defining browser instance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I am trying to use two browser instances in one test. After forking new driver instance and opening url in new window, protractor cannot find element on that window, even though elements are definitely visible.

Here is my code sample:

```
app.js
var app = {
browser: undefined,

useBrowser: function (b) {
    this.browser = b;
    return this;
},
useBrowserAlpha: function () {
    return this.useBrowser(browsers.alpha);
},

useBrowserBeta: function () {
    return this.useBrowser(browsers.beta);
},
}; module.exports = app;
```

Then, in test file I use it like this:

```
it('Test', function () {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    app.openGoogle();

    element(by.css('#lst-ib')).sendKeys('Hello');

    browsers.beta = browser.forkNewDriverInstance();
    app.useBrowserBeta();
    app.openGoogle();
    element(by.css('#lst-ib')).sendKeys('Hello');
});
```

In this test, first browser instance is opened and navigates to www.google.com, then types word 'Hello' in search bar, then second instance of browser is initiated, also opens www.google.com and then protractor sends keys to first browser search bar again. Any ideas on how it can be resolved will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try `browsers.beta.element` instead of simply `element` for the 2nd browser.

Comment: Yes, I agree. That would be the answer. ElementFinder and ExpectedConditions are tied to the browser instance.